# kubernetes networking: pod cannot reach nodes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, calico

I have kubernetes cluster with 3 masters and 7 workers. I use Calico as cni. When I deploy Calico, the calico-kube-controllers-xxx fails because it cannot reach 10.96.0.1:443.

```
2020-06-23 13:05:28.737 [INFO][1] main.go 88: Loaded configuration from environment config=&config.Config{LogLevel:"info", WorkloadEndpointWorkers:1, ProfileWorkers:1, PolicyWorkers:1, NodeWorkers:1, Kubeconfig:"", DatastoreType:"kubernetes"}
W0623 13:05:28.740128       1 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
2020-06-23 13:05:28.742 [INFO][1] main.go 109: Ensuring Calico datastore is initialized
2020-06-23 13:05:38.742 [ERROR][1] client.go 261: Error getting cluster information config ClusterInformation="default" error=Get https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: context deadline exceeded
2020-06-23 13:05:38.742 [FATAL][1] main.go 114: Failed to initialize Calico datastore error=Get https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: context deadline exceeded
```

this is the situation in the kube-system namespace:

```
kubectl get po -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-77d6cbc65f-6bmjg   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   56         4h33m
calico-node-94pkr                          1/1     Running            0          36m
calico-node-d8vc4                          1/1     Running            0          36m
calico-node-fgpd4                          1/1     Running            0          37m
calico-node-jqgkp                          1/1     Running            0          37m
calico-node-m9lds                          1/1     Running            0          37m
calico-node-n5qmb                          1/1     Running            0          37m
calico-node-t46jb                          1/1     Running            0          36m
calico-node-w6xch                          1/1     Running            0          38m
calico-node-xpz8k                          1/1     Running            0          37m
calico-node-zbw4x                          1/1     Running            0          36m
coredns-5644d7b6d9-ms7gv                   0/1     Running            0          4h33m
coredns-5644d7b6d9-thwlz                   0/1     Running            0          4h33m
kube-apiserver-k8s01                       1/1     Running            7          34d
kube-apiserver-k8s02                       1/1     Running            9          34d
kube-apiserver-k8s03                       1/1     Running            7          34d
kube-controller-manager-k8s01              1/1     Running            7          34d
kube-controller-manager-k8s02              1/1     Running            9          34d
kube-controller-manager-k8s03              1/1     Running            8          34d
kube-proxy-9dppr                           1/1     Running            3          4d
kube-proxy-9hhm9                           1/1     Running            3          4d
kube-proxy-9svfk                           1/1     Running            1          4d
kube-proxy-jctxm                           1/1     Running            3          4d
kube-proxy-lsg7m                           1/1     Running            3          4d
kube-proxy-m257r                           1/1     Running            1          4d
kube-proxy-qtbbz                           1/1     Running            2          4d
kube-proxy-v958j                           1/1     Running            2          4d
kube-proxy-x97qx                           1/1     Running            2          4d
kube-proxy-xjkjl                           1/1     Running            3          4d
kube-scheduler-k8s01                       1/1     Running            7          34d
kube-scheduler-k8s02                       1/1     Running            9          34d
kube-scheduler-k8s03                       1/1     Running            8          34d
```

Besides, also coredns cannot get internal kubernetes service.

Within a node, if I run `wget -S 10.96.0.1:443`, I receive a response.

```
wget -S 10.96.0.1:443
--2020-06-23 13:12:12--  http://10.96.0.1:443/
Connecting to 10.96.0.1:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
  HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
2020-06-23 13:12:12 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

But, if I run `wget -S 10.96.0.1:443` in a pod, I receive a **timeout error**.

Also, i cannot ping nodes from pods.

Cluster pod cidr is 192.168.0.0/16.

Comment: Is there any firewall that might block the connection? Or does your host have multiple NICs? It might happen that calico chose incorrect one. Could you post logs from `coredns` and `kube-apiserver` pod?

Comment: How did you fix issue ? i am also facing same issue

Comment: coredns logs are below ::  1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

Comment: API server logs are below :::                                                                                               
1 watch.go:251] unable to encode watch object *v1.WatchEvent: write tcp XX.XXX.XXXX:6443->XX.XXX.XXX.XX:42162: write: connection timed out (&streaming.encoder{writer:(*http2.responseWriter)(0xc00056d4a8), encoder:(*versioning.codec)(0xc00f04e960), buf:(*bytes.Buffer)(0xc00ff97080)})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolve recreating the cluster with different pod cidr